# ¿como puedo hacer esta consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Como puedo hacer que en lugar de un `0` salga otro mensaje en la cuenta de la tabla

```
    $notification_info = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as cuenta from notification WHERE viewed='viewed_no_$uid'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($notification_info) == 0)
    {
             echo 'No tienes Contenido';

    }else{  

        while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($notification_info)){

            echo ''.(string) $res["cuenta"].'';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($res["cuenta"] == 0) {
    echo 'NO TIENE CONTENIDO';
} else {
    echo (string)$res["cuenta"];
}
```

De esta forma si la cuenta es `0`, imprime `NO TIENE CONTENIDO`; en caso contrario, imprime el valor de `$res["cuenta"]`.

Comment: Antes que nada Bienvenido StackOverflow y si me funciono gracias amigo te devo ya te  voto y apruebo :)

Answer (score 2):

Probá esto:

```
$notification_info = mysql_query("SELECT CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'No tiene contenido' ELSE count(*) as cuenta from notification WHERE viewed='viewed_no_$uid'");
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, y para recalcar, en tu condición if inicial lo que estas preguntando el numero de filas devueltas por mysql, que en todo caso va a ser 1, sin importar el valor de cuenta. Por eso no te reconocía el valor real. Saludos!